# How to use filter grok in latest logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

It used to for parsing iptables logs used the following config:

```
filter {
  grok {
    tags => [“iptables”] 
    patterns_dir => “/etc/logstash/patterns”
    pattern => “%{IPTABLES}”
  }
}
```

But after updating of logstash to 1.3.3 version it doesn't work. How to use this one in latest version?

**EDIT:** It seems it doesn't work due deprecated tags. But I've rewrote the code above to:

```
filter {
  if "iptables" in [tags] {
    grok {
       patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
       match => ["message", "%{IPTABLES}"]
    }
  }
}
```

And I get no error anymore but also nothing happens with iptables logs.

My beaver config for iptables is:

```
[/var/log/iptables.log]
type: logstash:beaver
tags: iptables
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is pretty hard to troubleshoot. If you check your logs or run with `-v`, do you see any helpful error messages? Possible problems I see: your config sample seems to use [smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes#Smart_quotes), and you're using the [deprecated `tags` field](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/filters/grok#tags) instead of the [newer conditional system](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/configuration#conditionals).

Comment: Thanks. Are log events coming in? If you run your agent with `-v`, every input/filter/output plugin will log events as they run through the pipeline. Past that, is the `%{IPTABLES}` pattern capturing data? Since [LS 1.1](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/filters/grok#setting_named_captures_only), grok will only return only named capture patterns (ie: `%{WORD}` versus `%{WORD:some_field_name}`).

Comment: @rutter, yes log events are coming in. It seems the condition for filter does't works :(